# Chrome 54 is remembering the scroll position when it shouldn't

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling, refresh

In the new Chrome 54, if you scroll down on a page and then navigate to the address bar and press Enter, the page reloads and returns to the position scrolled to. Before, in 53, the page would reload as expected, but it would take me back to the top of the page, as expected.

In any browser, returning me to the previous position should only occur when refresh is hit via the button or via F5/Ctrl+F5.

I briefly searched the changelogs for 54 and couldn't find what I was looking for. Additionally, I couldn't find any related flags.

Does anyone perhaps know how to revert this behaviour back to the way it was in pre-54?

Comment: Happens in every website?

Comment: @Alfabravo - Yes, except `chrome://` pages, only tested with `flags`.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660388&can=2&q=scroll&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified#